# Groupby, count and calculate medians in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have this dataframe:

```
df:
      type . size .  margin .  height
0 .      A .    2 .       5 .       1
1 .      A .    3 .       4 .       1
2 .      B .    1 .       1 .       3
```

I want to groupby type, count the number of companies in each type and calculate the medians for all columns.

I know that for count is like this

```
df=df.groupby('type').count('type')
```

But is there a way to use a one liner and put everything in the same df?

Something like:

```
df=df.groupby('type').calculate_medians_and_counts
```

It should come out looking like this:

```
type    count   size   margin   height
   A        2    2.5      4.5        1
   B        1      1        1        3

(size, margin and height are the medians from df)
```

Comment: something like this maybe  `df.groupby('type').describe()` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html) by dictionary:

```
d = {'size':'median', 'margin':'median', 'height':'median', 'type':'size'}
```

Or if many columns is possible create `dict` dynamically:

```
d = dict.fromkeys(df.columns.difference(['type']), 'median')
d['type'] = 'size'
```

---

```
df = df.groupby('type').agg(d).rename(columns={'type':'count'}).reset_index()
```

Another alternative with [`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html):

```
df = df.groupby('type').median().join(df.type.value_counts().rename('count')).reset_index()
```

---

```
print (df)
  type  margin  size  height  count
0    A     4.5   2.5       1      2
1    B     1.0   1.0       3      1
```

Answer (score 1):

I will using `median` base on index level=0+ `value_counts`

```
pd.concat([df.set_index('type').median(level=0),df.type.value_counts()],1)
Out[787]: 
      size  margin  height  type
type                            
A      2.5     4.5     1.0     2
B      1.0     1.0     3.0     1
```